# TTimer as a component property issue

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-7

I have created a new component from (TShape ), and I make a Timer property as the next ::

```
property Timer:TTimer read FDeviceTimer write SetDeviceTimer ;
```

The purpose from this timer is that I want it to change the component height in the design time by using the next procedure :

```
procedure TFireDeviceWTimer.OnTimerRepaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
    //==================
    if ChangDim then begin
        Height:=Height+10;
        //Repaint;
        Sleep(FDeviceTimer.Interval);
        ChangDim:=False;
    end 
    else begin
        Height:=Height-10;
        //Repaint;
        Sleep(FDeviceTimer.Interval);
        ChangDim:=true;
    end;
end;
```

and it works good , but the issue that I have noted after using it in the run time , that it makes the application too slow ...

can anybody explain the reason & the solution for such issue ..

Thank u.

Comment: The OnTimer event is run using the UI thread (main thread) of the application. Since your putting two `Sleep` statements into this event, your blocking the UI thread not allowing it to do anything else (like repaint or respond to mouse/keyboard events). Just lose the `Sleep` statements and set a desired timer interval.

Comment: You'll have to throw this entire design away and learn how the event driven UI thread based design of Windows works

Comment: There is no good reason to expose a TTimer directly as a property. It should be used only as an internal detail inside the components implementation.

Comment: if OnTimerRepaint is the handler for FDeviceTimer.OnTimer, then just remove the two Sleep calls. And to make your code more usual, rename OnTimerRepaint DeviceTimerTimer. Remy advice is also very good. On expose the interval, not the timer.

Comment: Dear R.Hoek .. You have solved the Issue ..Many Thanks..

Comment: Dear Remy..the reason that I have used the timer inside the component body , is that when selecting many components(multi-select) i want them to vibrate (Change the height) at the same time .. and this could not be achieved I think by another way ,,,

Comment: @Issam Does your Timer property reference internal Timer class that is created with each component or to some external Timer. If it is the former then you won't have easy way of synchronizing vibrating of your components due the fact that in such case timers are created and started at different intervals so the firing of their events won't match.

Comment: @Issam As fpiette said, you can just create a property on the component specifying the desired interval, so therefor there’s no need to expose the TTimer. But when you have multiple component that need to be ‘moved’ you ca create one internal global timer and move component based on their specific interval...

Comment: @SilverWarior ,Yes its internal timer with each component , & I add Vibration property(as a Boolean ) to the component to trigger the timer ..

Comment: @Issam As I said you will have difficulty synchronizing timer intervals between multiple components. So while you could make them vibrate their vibrations wont be in sync. Maybe you could add your Timer to your components as class level Field meaning that reference to it is shared by all of your component instances. But I'm not sure how to fire OnTimer event for each instance of your component this way.

Comment: @Issam When you a set of controls vibrate at the same, you could also change the design: create a ‘vibrate’ component which internally has the timer and store a list of the controls that need to vibrate as collection in the vibrate component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason: The TTimer works in the same Thread of the main application.

Solution: Instead of a Timer, create a Thread that loops until the main component has been destroyed.

To do this, you could put in the constructor of the component something like this

```
FPaintThread := CreateAnonymouseThread(procedure
begin
    while assigned(Self) and (not Application.Terminated) do
    begin
        RepainInstruction;
        Sleep(100);
    end;
end);
FPaintThread.Start;
```

But remember to use TThread.Synchronize to interact with the main Thread objects to prevent bugs.